# OraOLEDB - O que é

Tags: oracle

O que é OraOLEDB? Qual sua função?

Por exemplo, tem um erro aqui no sistema do trabalho que só aparece o erro OraOLEDB, quais os motivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resumindo**

OraOLEDB é um driver feito no padrão OLEDB que serve para se conectar a bancos de dados Oracle.

Se aparece essa mensagem na aplicação da sua empresa, o mais provável é que o banco está fora do ar, caindo ou está muito ocupado processando queries lentas.

**Explicação longa**

Primeiramente, entenda que a OLEDB é uma API desenvolvida pela Microsoft com base no COM, Component Object Model, um modelo inventado pela própria Microsoft para garantir a interoperabilidade entre aplicações. Essa API representa uma biblioteca de interface COM que permite o acesso universal a diversas fontes de dados, inclusive, fontes de dados não SQL como, por exemplo, Microsoft Excel, Servidor de Email do Exchange e Serviços de Diretórios (Active Directory).

O design do OLEDB foca no conceito de consumidor (consumer) e provedor (provider).

Cada provedor implementa um conjunto de padrões de interfaces do COM para lidar com as requisições do consumidor. Um fabricante pode implementar interfaces COM opcionais para adicionar ainda mais funcionalidades ao seu provedor.

O **OraOLEDB** é uma implementação de um provedor OLEDB para acesso a banco de dados da Oracle.

Veja o diagrama da Oracle exemplificando o fluxo do OLEDB.

[image: Fluxo OraOLEDB]

Mais informações podem ser encontradas nos links.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/win.920/a95498/intro.htm (em inglês)

Comment: obrigada. sabe por que rankearam a pergunta negativamente?

Comment: É possível que seja por ela ser muito curta e não ter muitos detalhes. Principalmente, quando você cita o erro no sistema do seu trabalho. Você não pôs as condições de tal erro acontecer, não há um código, etc. Outro motivo talvez seja que sua pergunta sobre OraOLEDB não se encaixa perfeitamente na definição de programação, que é o foco do StackOverflow. Talvez um moderador poderia indicar essa pergunta para outro lugar como o [Super User](https://superuser.com).